# Нужен код cmd для изменения времени

Tags: windows, cmd

Нужно чтобы был cmd файл, в котором выводилась 
data 07.13.2017
а потом после 10 секунд все обратно возвращалось к прежнему времени (менять каждый раз cmd лень)
пробовал через службу времени что-то но все впустую, она вырубается при каждом date .....

Comment: Куда выводилась? `echo 07.13.2017` не подойдет?

Comment: Да и дата с 13 месяцем вызывает вопросы

Answer (score 0):

Есть у меня батник, который откатывает дату, пока запущена определенная программа.
Можете приспособить под свои нужды.:)

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/. " %%a in ('date/T') do set CDate=%%a-%%b-%%c
date = 12.12.2006
PING -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul
start c:\какая_то_программа.exe
PING -n 25 127.0.0.1>nul
date = %CDate%
```